# LM27762 voltage regulator LTspice simulation error

Tags: voltage-regulator, ltspice, simulation, texas-instruments

[LM27762 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm27762.pdf)

I imported [the latest model](https://www.ti.com/product/LM27762#design-tools-simulation) from the Design tools & simulation for the component.

I used the following layout from the datasheet as reference, capacitor values as defined in datasheet, and resistance values which are to generate the +3 V and -3 V.

[image: Reference Layout]

Here is my simulation setup and the error I run into:

[image: LTSpice layout and error]

These are the sim parameters I'm using:

[image: Simulation parameters]

PGOOD should be 0 V indicating correct voltage regulation and -3 V should be generated, but it just errors out. As far as I can tell, everything is the same as the reference diagram. The sim error arises only when EN- is enabled. I appreciate any help.

Comment: The error suggests you have some issue with the simulation parameters. What is the simulation step length you have choosen?

Comment: @PMF it does not work regardless of what simulation step length I choose. I always get that same error.

Comment: Try the standard stabilizing options: set gmin to something like 1e-10, cshunt to 1e-15, abstol to 1e-10, and reltol to 0.003, and see how that works. Also try using the `startup` flag. If all of that doesn't work, you can also try using the alternate solver and/or switching your integration method. Add a small series resistance to voltage sources; that can help sometimes too.

Comment: Seems like the subcircuit is very poorly constructed.  I tried playing around with the internal nodes for an hour, but still can't get it to run stably.  There is a line inside that creates a node called `CC` but it is not utilized anywhere.  Perhaps it's a bug?  You might be stuck with having to use PSPICE-FOR-TI to simulate this.  What are you trying to see by simulating this part?  The startup time/behavior?

Comment: @SteKulov Thanks for taking the time to do that. I have not used the component or a voltage regulator before so I just wanted to see general behavior and verify the setup is correct. I will probably just go ahead and order the PCB to test in hardware instead of fiddling with the simulators more.

Comment: @AuFries  Yeah, that's probably the best thing to do.  They also sell an EVAL board for $50, if you want to tinker around with various things on the bench before laying out your own board.  https://www.ti.com/tool/LM27762EVM